# What to use when i need a box with a border and some different text with different fonts and sizee

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi i have spend some days searching for the answer how to solve this
This is what i want, just made a image how it should look like

1. What is the best solution to use to solve this?
   [image]

I tryed to do this with a Frame but it just allowed be to use 1 content .

2. Can i use more then one content in some way
   ( Content can just have one setup of fontcolor and fontsize and so on. )

I just get to this part
[image]

Here i try to put a label with margin with - so it go above.
But this is really bad to to. because i need to have the implementation under the frams. like this.

**_stack.Children.Add(frame);**

**_stack.Children.Add(bordertext);**

and when i fill the frame with content the lable apear in another position because how it relate to the margin when the Frame get higher.

But if i put the lable implementation above the Frame then it appear in the background of the frame

**_stack.Children.Add(bordertext);**

**_stack.Children.Add(frame);**

And the label get weard with the shadow that i cant figure out how to get rid of.

C#

```
Frame frame = new Frame
            {                
                BorderColor = Color.Brown,              
                CornerRadius = 10,
                HasShadow = false,
                Margin = 10,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White, 
            };          
            
            
            Label bordertext = new Label( );
            bordertext.Text = "BorderText";
            bordertext.Margin = new Thickness(40, -65,0 , 0);
          
            bordertext.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            

            _stack.Children.Add(frame);
            _stack.Children.Add(bordertext);
```

PART OF THE SOLUTION

@Jason 's solution to put
the Content in a Stacklayout and then put it in a Frame Solves the problem with having more then one text with different font,sizes and stuff.

But i put a text outside the Stacklayout so i can have the Text on the border. But because i put the Bordertext first and then the Frame. Then the Border text gets in the background.
If i put it after the Frame then i gets in the front. But then i have a big problem with dynamic text that the BorderText will appear very strange depending on how much text.
How i cant put the BorderText in front even if i implement in before so i cant move it down a little bit.

_stack.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Bordertext", Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, -25) });
_stack.Children.Add(_frame);

[image]

Comment: put all of your content into a Layout container (Stack, Grid, etc) and put that inside your frame

Comment: Or possibly even the other way around, so that within the grid you can easily make the border label overlap the frame.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/boxview#rendering-text-decorations

Comment: @jason you cant do .Children.Add( on frame like stacklayout
-...... solution _frame.Content = _stack;

Comment: you assign the layout to the Frame's Content property, then add your children to the layout

Comment: I solved the content problem with your solution @Jason

Comment: @Jason, I have changed some part of the Solution please read the lowest part. I have picture of the problem =) Thanks a lot

Comment: you probably need a custom renderer to do this

Comment: @toolmakersteve

Comment: @Jason I have seen some talk about RaiseChild but don't get it to work
When i use it it dosent even show

Comment: Do the following answers meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

To compose a layout, first determine what boxes (rectangles) you need inside other boxes. Each "box" is some container (layout) type.

I see one box "A", the size of the parent-container, containing the border lines "B", overlaid by a box "C" that blocks part of one line, and contains a text "D".

I see a second box "E", inset slightly from the parent-container, which contains additional content "F".

To overlay multiple items, use a one-cell Grid, with children at (row,column) of 0,0 - which can be omitted because is default:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FormsApp1.MainPage">

    <Grid BackgroundColor="Violet">
        <!-- Border lines formed by one box visually "inside" another, via margins.
             Instead use "Rectangle" if need rounded corners. -->
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="10"/>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="LightCoral" Margin="16"/>

        <!-- Text "box" given size by putting inside a StackLayout. -->
        <!-- Some of these dimensions may not be needed. -->
        <StackLayout WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="30">
            <Label Text="Header Text" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="White" FontSize="18"
                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                   WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="30" Margin="20,0" Padding="20,0,0,0"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- this contains your contents. -->
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="10" Margin="40">
            <Label Text="Content line 1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White"/>
            <Label Text="Content line 2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

"Positioning" is done via "Margin" and "Padding" properties.

I've used various colors, so you can see the parts of this layout. "ContentPage" wrapper might not be needed; use whatever your app expects as topmost container.

layout of group' frame' with header text:

[image]