# .net MAUI Background vs BackgroundColor - what is the difference?

Tags: .net-maui

Using Visual Studio Community Edition 2022 to build a .Net MAUI project.

I tried searching the official docs, but did not find an answer.  Can someone explain the following?

**Questions:**

1. What is the difference between `Background` and `BackgroundColor`?
2. If neither (Background or `BackgroundColor`) is present, does the element inherit the background color from its parent?

Any other information with regard to how background color is determined would be appreciated.

If there is a page that answers the above question in the official docs, please post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The difference reside on the type of each property:

- `Background` is of type `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Brush` or any other type that sub class `Brush`like `SolidColorBrush`, `LinearGradientBrush` and `RadialGradientBrush`. Some properties especially used with Shapes (Rectangle, ellipse...) such `Fill`, `Stroke`... are of type `Brush`. With Brush you can do some advanced area's painting like with gradients.
- `BackgroundColor` is of type `Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color`.

I think `SolidColorBrush` is pretty close to `Color`.

[Brushes docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/brushes/).

2. Technically  it won't inherit the property value from it parent. Even that in cases where the default value (when the property is not set and value set by MAUI) of `BackgroundColor` is `Transparent`, could let believe that the `BackgroundColor` got inherited from the parent, but in fact it just shows the color underneath it; as @ToolmakerSteve explained in his comment; (could be the parent or any other element beneath in case of [overlapped Grid children](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37579754/5228202) or using `ZIndex`).

Comment: Re #2, it depends on what the app's default styles are. IMHO, Frame was not the best choice for this test. Many (most?) elements default to BackgroundColor="Transparent". That is they "show the color underneath". Which visually does look as if "the element inherits its background color from the parent". For there to be some different color, there must be some style or code somewhere, setting a different color.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I was not sure and was searching where and how MAUI might set the default value of this property for each control, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: `Brush` can also take values of Type `Color`, So you can Assign a White Color to a property of Type Brush...

Comment: @FreakyAli good point, under the hood it [performs a conversion](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/Brush.cs#L15) to return a `SolidColorBrush` which also sub class Brush.

Comment: With regard to visual controls is there any (official) documentation on what the default Background / BackgroundColors might be?

Comment: In the docs they don't mention all the default values of properties. An example of xamarin VisualElement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.backgroundcolor?view=xamarin-forms . keep in mind that the framework could change this property at each control level subclassing VisualElement. Overall i think most if not all controls have Transparent as a default value.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback / comments.  I will mark your response as the answer with regard to question 1.  With regard question 2 and any other information, as of today (15-Oct-2022), there is no official documentation that shows what values are used for BackgroundColor -- I guess the "answer" for those is: Try and see.