# Gradient page background in .NET MAUI app

Tags: xaml, maui

How do I set a page to have a linear background in a .NET MAUI app?

I tried defining a `LinearGradientBrush` in `Colors.xaml` and then assign it as a `StaticResource` -- see below -- but that doesn't seem to be working.

In `Colors.xaml`, I have this:

```xml
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PageGradientBackground" EndPoint="1,1">
     <GradientStop
         Color="{StaticResource UIOffWhite}"
         Offset="0.1"/>
     <GradientStop
         Color="{StaticResource UILightGray}"
         Offset="0.6"/>
     <GradientStop
         Color="{StaticResource UIMidGray}"
         Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

And then used it like this:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PageGradientBackground}">
    <!-- ... -->
</ContentPage>
```

I also tried defining it inline but that didn't work either. This is not even allowed actually:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <ContentPage.BackgroundColor>
        <LinearGradientBrush>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ContentPage.BackgroundColor>
    <!-- ... -->
</ContentPage>
```

Any idea how I can have a gradient background for a `ContentPage`?

Comment: Does this may be answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74034216/net-maui-background-vs-backgroundcolor-what-is-the-difference ? Maybe you can set `Background` instead of `BackgroundColor`?

Comment: @ewerspej Thanks, this solved a lot of XAML mysteries for me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `LinearGradientBrush` like the code below. You can put the `LinearGradientBrush` in the `<ContentPage.Background>` and it can work well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp7.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Background>
        
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Yellow"
                          Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="Green"
                          Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>

    </ContentPage.Background>
</ContentPage>
```

For more information, you can refer to this article [Linear gradient brushes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/brushes/lineargradient?view=net-maui-7.0).